# How can I solve my IR "case" problem in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get my IR remote that came with my Arduino board to control an RGB led, but the case number does not seem to be working... The error message says "'FF30CF' was not declared in this scope."
Here is my code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RED = 3;
int GREEN = 4;
int BLUE = 5;

int IR_RECEIVE_PIN = 2;
IRrecv IrReceiver(IR_RECEIVE_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
IrReceiver.enableIRIn();

pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
if(IrReceiver.decode(&results))
switch (results.value) {
      
case FF30CF:
Serial.println("case: RED led");
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
break;

case FF18E7:
Serial.println("case: GREEN led");
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
break;

case FF7A85:
Serial.println("case: BLUE led");
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
break;

Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
IrReceiver.resume();
}
}
```

I tried defining the IR case values, but then it gives me a different error message. Can someone please help me? And could my code work?

Comment: You have, for example, `case FF30CF`. In this context in the C/C++ languages, `FF30CF` is an *identifier*, not a *number*, and it doesn't recognize it since you haven't declared it as a variable. If you want to match hexadecimal value directly, you need `case 0xFF30CF`. Same for your other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared relevant details, code and HW specifications of your IR remote and receiver.

However, I'm guessing the problem is that that your "cases" are hexadecimal codes, but you are not formatting them as hexadecimal numbers.
A hexadecimal number should either start with a `0x` prefix, or start with a 0-9 digit and end with a `h` suffix.

So, e.g, the `FF30CF` in your code should really be `0xFF30CF`.